# Force node.js to use non-distro copy of OpenSSL

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, openssl

Is there a possibility to make Node.js to use my own compiled, local OpenSSL version? Can I set that with environment variables or some other way?

I have to use an older Node.js Version, but an own compiled OpenSSL version.

`node -pe process.versions`

tells me, Node.js is using the older OpenSSL lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to make Node.js to use my own compiled, local OpenSSL version?

Yes.

On Linux, use [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html). On OS X use, [`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html).

Be sure to choose a new OpenSSL that is binary compatible with whatever Node.js is linked against. For example, OpenSSL 0.9.7 and 0.9.8 are binary compatible, but not compatible with others like 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2 or 1.1.0. And OpenSSL 1.0.0, 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 are binary compatible.

Or, build Node.js from sources and statically link to the OpenSSL version you choose. It will avoid the LD preload tricks. (I'm side stepping `-rpath` since it does not work on OS X).

Comment: Yes, thanks. To build Node.js from source and statically link to OpenSSL run: ./configure --openssl-use-sys --shared-openssl-includes=INCLUDEPATH --shared-openssl-libpath=LIBPATH

Comment: But I don't think that Node.js is not using the OpenSSL-EVP API by default, because there are no performance improvements... Can I also force Node.js to use the EVP API?